# What is the best way for me to clear the terminal but not stop the program in Python?

Tags: python, game-development

I am looking to make a fairly comprehensive text-based game in python as a project to learn it better, however I do not want the terminal to be filled up with multiple different screens all printing on top of each other. I had the idea to clear each screen, such as title screen or inventory screen whenever the player switches, however I have no idea if there is a statement or module to do that. I have googled for a couple hours now and haven't found anything, so I was hoping one of you might know. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Tried Tkinter, and a couple other modules as well as watch a few videos but nothing seems to clear the screen without ending the program. I appreciate the help if you have it, thank you!

Comment: You should have searched `how to clear terminal`. Screens and terminals are very different after all. :^)

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal supports ANSI escape codes then:

```
CLS = '\x1B[2J'

def cls():
    print(CLS, end='', flush=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to clear whole screen, then use,

```
import os

print("Your first string")
os.system('cls') # if you're using windows  else os.system('clear')
print('your second string')
```

If you want to clear one line, then use

```
import time

print('Your first string', end='\r')
time.sleep(2)
print('Your second string')
```

**Note**: here I used time module because you won't see the `Your first string`
If you don't use that module.

I hope this will help.

**Edit**:

My second suggestion won't work if the first string length is bigger than the second string. So to solve it you can use this,

```
import sys
import time

print("Your first string")

time.sleep(2) # Added a delay to see the first string otherwise you won't see it.

# Clear the first string
sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')
sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')

print("Your second string")
```

Comment: Your second suggestion doesn't work well when the second string is shorter than the first

Comment: Thank you for showing that issue to me. So I edited my suggestion. Now the third suggestion (Edited one) will work nicely.

Answer (score -3):

Try "clear_screen" function in OS module.
You can use it whenever you want to clear the screen before print function.

Comment: There is no *clear_screen* function in the *os* module